# Lambdas in C# Capturing Outer Variables - Pls explain example from book "C# in nutshell 5.0"

Tags: c#, lambda

What difference between

```
static Func<int> Natural()
{
  int seed = 0;
  return () => seed++;      // Returns a closure
}
```

and

```
static Func<int> Natural()
{
  return() => { int seed = 0; return seed++; };
}
```

Why

```
static void Main()
{
  Func<int> natural = Natural();
  Console.WriteLine (natural());       
  Console.WriteLine (natural());         
}
```

shows 0 1 for first Natural() and 0 0 for second one? Thanks!

Comment: I guess you are also irrated why the second one returns 0 instead of 1, thats because you wrote seed++ this should be changed to ++seed.

Comment: In the first example `seed` is outside the returned function, in the second it's inside the function

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference is that in the first version, you're declaring a variable and then *capturing* the variable in the lambda expression. The variable itself "survives" across multiple invocations of the delegate.

In the second example, you're declaring a variable *inside* the lambda expression, so every time the delegate is executed, the variable effectively starts again.

To put it another way, it's the difference between:

```
class NaturalImpl
{
    public int seed;

    public int Method()
    {
        return seed++;
    }
}

Func<int> natural = new NaturalImpl().Method;
```

and:

```
class NaturalImpl
{
    public int Method()
    {
        int seed = 0;
        return seed++;
    }
}

Func<int> natural = new NaturalImpl().Method;
```

Note the difference between the *instance* variable in the first version, and the *local* variable in the second.

(That's not exactly what the implementation of the second form would look like; it would be a static method in the enclosing class as it's stateless, but...)

Comment: Sorry about rolling that back, I was doubting myself for a second (I previously approved the suggested edit).

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, whenever `Natural` is called it returns a function that refers *to the same `seed` variable each time* (the one that's defined inside `Natural` itself).

In the second case it returns a function that refers *to a different `seed` variable each time* (the one that's defined inside the body of said function).

It stands to reason that in the first case each returned function will be able to "see" changes to `seed` made by the others because all of them are working on the same value.